# One second difference when comparing two Date() with difference of one day

Tags: java, spring, date, time, java-time

I wrote simple TimeService with method `getDateAfter(int days)` and test for it:

```
@Test
@Order(7)
public void getDateAfterCorrect() throws InterruptedException {
    waitIfNeeded();
    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime tomorrow = timeService.getDateAfter(1).toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    long diff = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(today, tomorrow);
    long secondsAtDay = 86400;
    Assertions.assertEquals(secondsAtDay, diff);
}
```

It should be 86400 seconds at day, but `diff` is 86399.
I tried to take that one part of code could be executed in another time than other into account by implementing `waitIfNeeded()` method

```
private void waitIfNeeded() throws InterruptedException {
    var currentMillis = Instant.now().get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND);
    if (currentMillis > 500) {
        Thread.sleep(1000 - currentMillis);
    }
}
```

Do You have any idea why I am not able to make this test and other possible things that can be wrong here (I assume things like how programming languages are dealing with step year, etc...)

Comment: Well, without knowing what `timeService.getDateAfter()` does it’s hard to tell. Could you perhaps provide a [mre]?

Comment: Prefer `ZonedDateTIme` over `LocalDateTIme` for the current time in the default time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get test simplified and working, now it is OK:

```
@Test
@Order(7)
public void getDateAfterCorrect() throws InterruptedException {
    waitIfNeeded();
    long today = timeService.getDate().toInstant().getEpochSecond();
    long tommorow = timeService.getDateAfter(1).toInstant().getEpochSecond();
    Assertions.assertEquals(86400, tommorow - today);
}
```

but It is still interesting why using other method of comparing that two dates produced such results, if someone with deep level knowledge can answer it, probably few people will be interested.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util` Date-Time API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Apart from that, instead of performing the calculation (subtraction) yourself, you use [`Instant#until`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) which returns the duration in the specified `ChronoUnit`.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is a sample Instant. In your case, it will be returned by
        // timeService.getDate().toInstant()
        Instant today = Instant.now();

        // This is a sample Instant after one day. In your case, it will be returned by
        // timeService.getDateAfter(1).toInstant()
        Instant tomorrow = today.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

        long seconds = today.until(tomorrow, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

        // In your case, you will use Assertions.assertEquals(86400, seconds);
        System.out.println(seconds);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
86400
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wWzOEv)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

### The explanation: why 86399? Lack of precision

I am assuming that `timeService.getDateAfter(1)` returns an old-fashioned `Date` object. You shouldn’t be using `Date` in your code anymore, it’s been replaced by java.time, the modern Java date and time API that you are also using, many years ago. But we’re still curious why your code using `Date` didn’t give the expected result of 86 400 seconds in a day.

`Date` has milliseconds precision. java.time has nanosecond precision, and since Java 9 the `now` methods of many of the classes have microsecond precision on most platforms. So for example `LocalDateTime.now()` returns 0.001234 seconds past a whole second. Some microseconds later, maybe at 0.001432 past the whole second, your time service returns a `Date` worth 0.001 seconds past the same whole second. Between today at 0.001234 and tomorrow at 0.001 is not a whole day, not fully 24 hours, so the difference in seconds is truncated to 86 399.

When I ran your code in a loop, the first time I got 86 400. It must be because I passed a full millisecond of the second between the two calls. Maybe because of JVM warm-up. The following times I got 86 399.

### A possible fix

One way to obtain consistent precision is to truncate everything to milliseconds. Or even to seconds. With the following change to your code I got 86 400 consistently.

```
    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
```

I got the same result when using `ChronoUnit.SECONDS` instead of `.MILLIS`. I believe that this also somewhat explains why the change in your own answer worked. I think you need to be aware, though, that some time does elapse between your two calls, and you cannot control how much. So you may get 86 401 or even a still higher number on rare occasions. Even if I didn’t observe it in my few runs.

I did once work in a place where some of the very many unit tests failed sporadically. It was quite annoying and a source of distrust in the code even when I made it a habit to type comments into the unit tests in question about their sporadic failures. Please do not put yourself and your co-workers in the same situation.